# How can I get SetState to stop overwriting my component tags

Tags: react-native, tags, setstate

I am using these tags in my react native app: https://github.com/peterp/react-native-tags
Being a react rookie I have a problem with SetState. I have set-up the tags like this:

```
<Tags
      initialText=""
      textInputProps={{
           placeholder: "Servicable Postcodes"
      }}
      initialTags={["3121"]}
      onChangeTags={(tags) => this.changeTags(tags)}
      inputStyle={{ backgroundColor: "white", borderBottomWidth: 1 }}
      renderTag={({ tag, index, onPress, deleteTagOnPress, readonly }) => (
           <TouchableOpacity key={${tag}-${index}} onPress={onPress}>
                <Text style={styles.tagStyle}>{tag}</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
 />
```

```
 changeTags(newtags) {
      //this.setState({ myTags: newtags.toString()});
      var tagList = newtags.toString();
      /*this.setState({myTags: tagList}, function () {
           console.log(this.state.myTags);
      });*/
  }
```

Adding tags works like this [3121] [1111] [2222]

So that code works well. As soon as I uncomment the setState it will run everything like normal but the tag will not get added to the list. So if I add 1111 my console log will  be `3121, 1111` (But 1111 will not show as as a tag) then if i try to add another it will be `3121, 2222` etc.

I think because it re-renders with setState the tag is never added/overwritten and I just keep getting left with the single 3121 tag. Or maybe i'm a react noob and have no idea.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in saying that each render will cause the `Tag` component to reset back to `3121`.

To avoid this you need to store your current tags in your state like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = { tags: ['3121'], myTags: "3121" }; // This line

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Tags
          initialText=""
          textInputProps={{
            placeholder: 'Servicable Postcodes',
          }}
          initialTags={this.state.tags} // This line
          onChangeTags={tags => this.changeTags(tags)}
          inputStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white', borderBottomWidth: 1 }}
          renderTag={({ tag, index, onPress, deleteTagOnPress, readonly }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity key={`${tag}-${index}`} onPress={onPress}>
              <Text style={styles.tagStyle}>{tag}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  changeTags(newtags) { // This function
    this.setState({ tags: newtags, myTags: newtags.toString() }, () =>
      console.log(this.state)
    );
  }
}
```

This means for each render (which will happen every time a tag is added as you are calling setState), the `Tag` component will render the tags you have stored in the state.

I have also included another member in your state called `myTags`, which maps to the string value of your tags as it seems like this was necessary from your previous code.

[Here](https://snack.expo.io/@campbellmg/restless-cashew) is a working snack

Comment: Oh man I was close. Thanks for getting me over the line. Gold star for you.